# It works when I put '.handlebars' at the end of the document and it doesn't work when I put '.hbs'

Tags: handlebars.js, hbs

It doesn't work when I make '.hbs' at the end of the handlebars document. Shouldn't it normally work?

index.handlebars (working)

index.hbs (dont working)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUrTz.png)

webpack is handlebars-4.0.6.tgz

Comment: How is your compilation set up? Some webpack or other stuff?

Comment: This is likely due to a configuration issue. I think you need provide more information.

Comment: webpack is handlebars-4.0.6.tgz